# Remove-Item command is not removing a folder and its contents

Tags: powershell

I have an application that will be un installed across our estate, so I am creating a PowerShell script to do this (it will be distributed through Intune).  However after the uninstall a folder and 2 files remain.  I added in Remove-Item but it will not remove the folder and content even with -Force and -Recurse included as it states it is in use, but I can manually delete the folder and contents without any issues.

My script is (I have changed sensitive information)

```
$FileName = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\my_app\app1.exe"
if (Test-Path $FileName) {
Write-Host "File Exists"
}
else
{
Write-Host "File Doesn't Exists"
exit
}
cd "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\my_app"
.\Update.exe --uninstall
Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\my_app -Force -Recurse
```

The actual error states

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove the item at 'C:\Users\superuser\AppData\Local\my_app' because it is in use
At line:21 char:1
+ Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\my_app - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: There is probably a service running that has access to the files. See: [Is there a registry key to tell windows to delete a file at next startup?](https://superuser.com/q/58479/1085094)

Comment: You cd into that directory and then try to delete it. You’ll need to cd elsewhere first

Answer (score 2):

You change locations into the same directory you are trying to delete. You need to change out of that directory. You have a few options here:

### The Obvious Solution (Once You Know the Issue)

Change out of the directory:

```
cd .. # any path that is not part of the directory tree you want to delete
```

But PowerShell has some more useful ways to traverse directories. Read on for more information.

### Solution 2: Windows PowerShell - Use the Location Stack

Opt for using [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-5.1) and [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location?view=powershell-5.1) instead of `cd` (aliased to [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/Set-location?view=powershell-5.1)).
`Push/Pop-Location` use the location stack. Use `Push-Location` to change to new directories and `Pop-Location` to walk backwards. In your case, this would work:

```
Push-Location "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\my_app"
.\Update.exe --uninstall
Pop-Location # This will return to the previous directory
Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\my_app -Force -Recurse
```

### Solution 3: PowerShell Core - Use `cd -`

If you can utilize PowerShell Core, the same concept applies but PowerShell Core supports the bash-like `cd -` and `cd +` since version 6.2. Similar to using `Push/Pop-Location`, you can walk backwards and forwards to the directories you've been to. In your case, `cd -` would work like so:

```
cd "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\my_app"
.\Update.exe --uninstall
cd - # This will return to the previous directory
Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\my_app -Force -Recurse
```

From the [`Set-Location` documentation for PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/Set-location?view=powershell-7.1):

> PowerShell 6.2 added support for `-` and `+` as a values for the **Path** parameter. PowerShell maintains a history of the last 20 locations that can be accessed with `-` and `+`. This list is independent from the location stack that is accessed using the **StackName** parameter.